# Bockstein homomorphim and obstruction of spin-c structure

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

Bockstein homomorphim and obstruction of spin-c structure: Let $w_2$ be the Stiefel Whintney class of manifold $M$. Let the Bockstein homomorphim $\beta$ be the 
$$
H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2,M) \to H^3(\mathbb{Z},M),
$$
such that $\beta(w_2)$ is the integral cohomology class.

> Is this true that for certain dimensions of $M=M^d$, say $d=5$, the existence of such a nontrivial $\beta(w_2)$ indicates the obstruction of the spin$^c$ structure of $M$? How do we show this?

Comment: $SU(3)/SO(3)$ (called the Wu manifold) is a 5-dimensional example of this.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more explicit? You mean it is an obstruction, only in 5d?

Comment: An oriented vector bundle $E$ has a $\text{spin}^c$ structure iff $\beta w_2(E) = 0$. You can prove this via obstruction theory, as one possible approach. This is just a fact for all vector bundles over (paracompact) spaces. Now, if $E = TM$, this automatically vanishes for dimensions up to 4 - for easy reasons when the dimension is at most 3. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-spinc-structure) for dimension 4. The Wu manifold is a simple 5-manifold that does not carry a spin^c structure, showing these arguments don't generalize.

Comment: Wu x torus is also not spin^c, so you would get examples in any higher dimension.

Comment: Thanks. How about SU(N)/SO(N) manifold in higher dim?

Comment: Does SU(N)/SO(N) manifold in higher dim offer similar statements of obstruction?

Comment: I believe that is spin when N is even, and is neither spin nor spin-c when N is odd. This seems to be a difficult calculation. If you have some specific reason to care about whether that manifold is spin-c I can write up the calculation as an answer to a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Mike- I will post one accordingly at the Mathoverflow. Thanks - I dont have any use for it - but I am happy to know about it.

Comment: @Mike, I just post it on MO - see the manifolds and spin geometry tags.